# Iterating over a HashMap with a Pair(x,y) as the key

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap

I have a HashMap:

```
resources = new HashMap<Pair, Resource>();
```

That I have instantiated...

```
resources.put(new Pair(x,y), new Resource());
```

Pair is a custom Pair class that I have created that has overridden .equals and .hashMap to avoid duplicate keys.

I want to iterate over resources so I can identify the unique instances I have created. More specifically, I need to identify the unique (x,y) pairs.

I have found solutions for iterating over HashMaps, but I'm a little confused on how to adapt this (shown below) to work with a key that is a Pair.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "I need to identify the unique (x,y) pairs." All keys in a `Map` are unique.

Comment: from Map.put()-javadoc: **If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.**

Comment: ..and if you *want* to iterate over the entries, they would look like `Map.Entry<Pair, Resource>` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It's no different. `Map` and `Map.Entry` are generic, so you specify parametrized types when you construct the map.

```
Map<Pair, String> keyToValue = new HashMap<>();
// put stuff in it
for (Map.Entry<Pair, String> entry: keyToValue.entrySet()) {
    Pair pair = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
    // do stuff
}
```

In fact, your `Pair` class should probably be generified itself -- `Pair<T,U>`.

As for getting the unique pairs, you could just do `Set<Pair> uniquePairs = keyToValue.keySet()` or, if you didn't need the corresponding values at all, you could just use a HashSet -- `Set<Pair> uniquePairs = new HashSet<>()`. They will be as unique as your implementations of `Pair.hash` and `Pair.equals` define them to be.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you mean you have overridden equals() and hashCode() methods in Pair class right? 
How do you define unique Pair? I hope your definition of uniqueness is not based on equals() because if it is the case then all the key of HashMap is unique